# Js function should return a specific string but is behave weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

i know this shold be a very simple task, but i'm trying to understand more about JS and how it behave, this function should behave like this:

- If a word begins with a consonant, take the first consonant or consonant cluster, move it to the end of the word, and add "ay" to it.
- If a word begins with a vowel, just add "way" at the end.

examples:

california => aliforniacay 
algorithm  => algorithmway 
schwartz   => artzschway

california and algorithm words are working as expected but schwartz doesnt, my output with this:
omarigg@omarigg-System:$ node pigLatinExercise.js 
chwartzsay 
hwartzscay 
wartzschay 
artzschway  <= my expected result 
schwartzway

i dont understand why the variable newPhrase2 is equal to "artzschway" inside of the else scope, but when i return the same variable outside of the for scope, change its value to "schwartzway"

How can i handle this scope issue?
Also i know this problem is more viable to solve with regEx tools but i want to handle this like this way as a way to learn more.

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var arrayToAdd = [];

  function cond(index) {
    return (str[index] === 'a' ||
      str[index] === 'e' ||
      str[index] === 'i' ||
      str[index] === 'o' ||
      str[index] === 'u')
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length + 1; i++) {
    if (cond(i)) {
      //console.log('vowel at first')
      var newPhrase2 = str + 'way'
      break
      //console.log(str)
    } else {
      //console.log('not vowel at first')
      let theWord = str[i];
      arrayToAdd.push(theWord);
      //console.log(arrayToAdd)
      let newPhrase = str.slice(i + 1, str.length + 1)
      //console.log(newPhrase);
      let newPhrase2 = newPhrase + arrayToAdd.join("") + 'ay'
      console.log(newPhrase2);
    }
  }

  //console.log(arrayToAdd.join(""));
  // arrayToAdd.join("");
  // newPhrase = newPhrase + arrayToAdd + 'ay'
  //console.log(newPhrase2)
  return newPhrase2;
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("schwartz"))
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variable outside the loop?

Comment: `i<=str.length+1` is wrong

Comment: @DaveNewton That doesn't make a difference with `var` declarations, only `let` and `const`.

Comment: @Barmar `let newPhrase2=`?

Comment: Ah, I was confused because he has `var newPhrase2 = str + 'way'` in the `if`.

Comment: The scope of `let` variables is only the that block. So the `newPhrase2` in the `else` block goes away.

Comment: understand guys, appreciate it so much your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code out, it should work fine !

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  let stringToAdd = '';
  let newPhrase2 = '';
  let newPhrase = '';

  function cond(index) {
    return (str[index] === 'a' ||
      str[index] === 'e' ||
      str[index] === 'i' ||
      str[index] === 'o' ||
      str[index] === 'u')
  }
  
  if (cond(0)) {
      newPhrase2 = str + 'way';
      console.log(newPhrase2);
      return newPhrase2;
    }
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        
      let theWord = str[i];
      if(!cond(i)) {
        stringToAdd += theWord;
        newPhrase = str.slice(i + 1, str.length + 1);
      }
      else break;
    }
  }
    
  newPhrase2 = newPhrase + stringToAdd + 'ay';
  console.log(newPhrase2);
  return newPhrase2;
}

translatePigLatin("schwrz");
```

The reason why your code not working properly is because you have messed up the conditional logics.

You should check for the first letter without getting into the loop. If its not a vowel, then get into the loop and loop through until you find a vowel.

I think its pretty self-explanatory after that.

Comment: Thanks sanyaldip! appreciate it so much your explicit explanation, i understand that i should have put the for loop only when it is not a vowel, now i understand my mistake, thanks u so much!